# Understanding foldr's definition

Tags: haskell

The definition of foldr is (according to https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#local-6989586621679020249)

```
foldr            :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

That means the first argument is of type `(a -> b -> b)`, the second `b`, the third `[a]` and returns `b`.

If we look at an example:

```
foldr (-) 54 [10, 11]
```

Doesn't `-` take two of the same type, and returns the same type? So shouldn't it be `(a -> a -> a)`?

Comment: `a -> a -> a` is a "specific" case of `a -> b -> b`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Are there times when `-` can substract two different types though? It's can't subtract an integer with a list right?

Comment: no, the `(-)` function is defined in the `Num` typeclass as `Num a => a -> a -> a`. You can use functions like `fromIntegral` that convrt one number type to another.

Comment: Note that the type of `(-)` constrains the type of `foldr`'s result: `foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`, but `foldr (-) :: Num a =>  a -> [a] -> a`, not `b -> [a] -> b`.

Comment: Perhaps just an example where `a` and `b` are different types: `let f = foldr (\x y-> if (fst x > 0) then y else (y + snd x)) 0` works on a list of tuples and returns the sum of all second arguments where the first argument is greater than zero. E.g. `f [(1,2), ((-1),4), (3,2)] = 4`.

Comment: How's about this for another example: `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`, so we can do `foldr (:) [] "a list"`. This one's particularly easy to work out by hand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that the signature of the function is `a -> b -> b` does *not* mean that `a` and `b` should be different types. It means `a` and `b` *can* be different types.

If you for example use `(-) :: Num c => c -> c -> c`, then Haskell will deduce that:

```
foldr ::          (a -> b -> b) -> (b -> ([a] -> b))
(-)      Num c =>  c -> c -> c
----------------------------------------------------
a ~ c, b ~ c
```

So `a` and `b` and `c` are thus the same type here. The type of `foldr (-)` thus has type:

```
foldr (-) :: Num c => c -> ([c] -> c)
```

`foldr (-)` thus takes a number of type `c`, and returns a function that maps a list of `c`s to a `c`.

Answer (score 2):

I like to explain this subject in this terms:

```
f :: a -> b -> b
f x y = y
```

That's completely true, `a` and `b` could be different, and have different types, but it doesn't says anywhere it can't be of the same type, so:

```
v = f 'c' True
v :: Bool
```

here, `f :: Char -> Bool -> Bool`
but you can also do something like:

```
v2 = f False True
v3 = f False False

v2 :: Bool
v3 :: Bool
```

and here `f :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool`

Different is when you want those two to be of the same type and restrict them, example:

```
sameTypeTuple :: a -> a -> (a,a)
sameTypeTuple x y = (x,y)
```

you are restricting the arguments to be of the same type:

```
v4 = sameTypeTuple 'a' 'b'
v4 :: (Char, Char)
```

BUT

```
v5 = sameTypeTuple 'c' True
```

will give to you

```
 error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘Bool’
    • In the second argument of ‘sameTypeTuple’, namely ‘True’
      In the expression: sameTypeTuple 'c' True
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = sameTypeTuple 'c' True
```

Finally:

in `foldr (-) 54 [10, 11]` you are saying that `a` and `b` will be of type `Num a0 => a0)` of type `a0` (the type is `a0` and not `Num`, `Num` is the constrait, the typeclass)